How do I rename the Wordpress author without changing owner, or developers/contributors?
@wp_devs
Been working on several plugins recently and realised I don't know how to rename their owner, or as wordpress puts it "By [name]" at the top - so as to promote continuity between all my plugins.
Take for example, Mullenberg's plugin enter image description here on the /plugins/ page you can see his name, but if you click on the page you see the contributors and developers, which is again different.
Any ideas?

At first I though this was an easy fix: change the readme file. But that changes the contributors and not the owner.
Then I tried changing the "owner" in the wordpress managment board, but that also seems incongruent with the 'By [name]'...


The plugin file for the Hello Dolly plugin is just https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/hello.php, there is nothing else. Your screenshot looks like it is showing info from https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/ - so any additional information you see is probably not anywhere in the code, but has been set when the plugin was added to the WP plugins list.

It is not as easy as changing a field. The current owner has to transfer the ownership. In the plugin -> development -> advanced view the owner will have the option to transferit to you if you are already able to commit to the plugin:

I hope this helps
